# How to add a column to a polars DataFrame using .with_columns()

Tags: python-polars

I am currently creating a new column in a polars data frame using

```
predictions = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
df['predictions'] = predictions
```

where `predictions` is a numpy array or list containing values I computed with another tool.

However, polars throws a warning, that this option will be deprecated.
How can the same result be achieved using `.with_columns()`?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72245243/polars-how-to-add-a-column-with-numerical/72245435#72245435

Comment: Thankd, yes that answers it. IMO it would be great to add the linked answer to the "Coming from Pandas" guide: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/coming_from_pandas.html

Comment: It is there, see https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/coming_from_pandas.html#column-assignment

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The values in the numpy array or list `predictions` can be add to a polars table using:

```py
predictions = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
df.with_columns(pl.Series(name="predictions", values=predictions))
```

Comment: Just a heads up, with_column is now deprecated. The correct form is now with_columns (plural).